# What is Haskell way to generate list of symbols from Start character to Finish character?

Tags: haskell, linked-list

Let's I want to generate all english alphabet characters `([a, b, ..., z])` in reverse order. How I have to do this?

My solution is:

```
returnPrev c = chr (ord c - 1)

generateList t = unfoldr (\b -> if b == (returnPrev (fst t)) then Nothing else Just (b, returnPrev b)) (snd t)

*Main> generateList ('a', 'z')
"zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
```

Is there more right solution?

Comment: Have you tried `['z', 'y' .. 'a']`? If you specify the first two elements in the range, Haskell uses that as interval.

Comment: @Jubobs, o, it is better way, than mine :)

Comment: @Jubobs More specifically, it gets translated to a call to `enumFromThenTo`, for which the default implementation converts the arguments to `Int`s, expands that `enumFromThenTo`, then converts back to your specific `Enum` type.  [It's literally defined as](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Enum.html) `enumFromThenTo x1 x2 y = map toEnum [fromEnum x1, fromEnum x2 .. fromEnum y]`.

Comment: @bheklilr That's the default definition, yes. But for `Char`, there's a specialized one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this case you can use `['z', 'y' .. 'a']` and you'll get the list you want, and this will actually work for any `Enum`, since it translates to the call `enumFromThenTo 'z' 'y' 'a'`.